Wordpress custom form handler suddenly conflicts with Elementor plugin (headers already sent error)
I have a simple custom form that's been working fine for more than a year, but now is causing this error:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
(output started at
/home/oakbdvsm/public_html/new/wp-content/plugins/elementor/modules/image-loading-optimization/module.php:99)
in /home/oakbdvsm/public_html/new/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line
1435

When I looked at line 99 of .../image-loading-optimization/module.php I see this:
    public function flush_header_buffer( $content ) {
        $buffer_status = ob_get_status();

        if ( ! empty( $buffer_status ) &&
            1 === $buffer_status['type'] &&
            get_class( $this ) . '::handle_buffer_content' === $buffer_status['name'] ) {
            ob_end_flush();

ob_end_flush() is line 99
Here is my code for the custom form that just asks the user for the name of a street and if the user inputs "Broadway" it redirects to another page:
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Form Handler
Description: Handles the custom form submission.
*/

function custom_form_handler() {
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && is_page('Members Only')) {
        $streetName = sanitize_text_field($_POST['street_name']); // Sanitize the input.

        // Check if the "Street Name" field is valid
        if ($streetName === "Broadway") {
            // Redirect to the "Members Only Success" page.
            wp_redirect(site_url('/membersonly-success/'));
            exit();
        } else {
            // Display the form with an error message.
            echo "Invalid street name.";
//            display_myzzzcustom_form();
        }
    }
}

function display_myzzzcustom_form() {
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        Street Name <input type="text" name="street_name">&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
    <?php
}

add_action('init', 'custom_form_handler');

function custom_form_shortcode() {
    ob_start(); // Start output buffering.

    custom_form_handler();
    display_myzzzcustom_form();

    return ob_get_clean(); // Return the buffered content.
}

add_shortcode('custom_form', 'custom_form_shortcode');


The "headers already sent" error happens when the form is posted.
Any ideas on why I'm getting that error and how to resolve it?

The mentioned script has already flushed the output buffer before your code runs, https://github.com/elementor/elementor/blob/main/modules/image-loading-optimization/module.php#L93 - so you will either need to find a way to make your own code run earlier (perhaps via a lower $priority in your add_action call), or disable this image optimization in the Elementor settings.

Thanks very much @C3roe. There is an option in Elementor to disable image optimization, and that did resolve the conflict. Is there a way I could have made my code less likely to cause a conflict?
